# manually order coefficients in coefplot

Tags: r, coefplot

I would like to manually sort the coefficients in a `coefplot`. Previous [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D%20%5Bcoefplot%5D%20coefficient) only achieve ordering by (decreased) `magnitude`, which is not what I want.

Consider the below example:

```
library(coefplot)
data(tips, package = "reshape2")
mod1 <- lm(tip ~ day + sex + smoker + sex * smoker, data = tips)
coefplot.glm(mod1)
```

How would I achieve a coefficient order with `sexMale:smokerYes` on top and `daySat`, `dayThu`, `daySun` (and then the rest) without relying on their magnitude?

Thanks in advance for pointing me to a solution. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `coefplot.glm()` is outputting a `ggplot` object, you can access the data object and re-level the y factor:

## Create `ggplot` object

```
library(coefplot)
data(tips, package = "reshape2")
mod1 <- lm(tip ~ day + sex + smoker + sex * smoker, data = tips)
gg <- coefplot.glm(mod1)
gg
```

[image]

## Re-level y factor

```
gg$data$Coefficient <- factor(gg$data$Coefficient, levels = rev(c("sexMale:smokerYes", "daySat", "dayThur", "daySun", "smokerYes", "sexMale", "(Intercept)")))
gg
```

[image]